# MVC ActionResult calling another ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ActionResult calling another ActionResult.

I have a call to an ActionResult in my case statement which doesn't work. Here is what I have:

```
   public ActionResult GetReport(string pNum)
   {
   ....

        switch (methodId)
        {
          case 1:
          case 5:                
           {
             var actionResult =  GetP1Report("33996",false)  as ActionResult;
              break;
           }
         }

         return actionResult; 
       }
```

I get the following error: *'actionResult' does not exist in the current context*

If I do the following it works but not quite what I need:

```
    public ActionResult GetReport(string pNum)
   {
      ....

       var actionResult =  GetP1Report("33996",false)  as ActionResult;

        switch (methodId)
        {
          case 1:
          case 5:                
           {
             // var actionResult =  GetP1Report("33996",false)  as ActionResult;
              break;
           }
         }

         return actionResult; 
       }
```

How do I get the actionResult to work in my case statement such that it is visible when I do

```
    return actionResult
```

Comment: have you considered `RedirectToAction`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just declare it first (with a default value, I guess), outside of the switch statement:

```
 ActionResult actionResult = null;
 switch (methodId)
    {
      case 1:
      case 5: // PVT, PVT-WMT
      {
          actionResult =  GetP1Report("33996",false)  as ActionResult;
          break;
       }
     }

 return actionResult ?? new View();
```

Note: I added the `?? new View()` as a default value, in case none of the cases assign anything to `actionResult` -- modify this as needed.

Comment: Assignment to null is redundant.

Comment: @Kugel no it's not, you have to assign something to it, or you get a `use of unassigned local variable "actionResult"` compiler error.

Comment: @Kugel well, to be exact, you *could* leave it undefined if *every* case assigns something to it, but that's not the case the Op presented.

Comment: Why not ActionResult actionResult = new View() since the view isn't executed until after the Action has been called?

Comment: @dbaseman exactly if you use it unassigned you have clear error from compiler. If you set it to null, you may get NullReferenceException during runtime.

Comment: @ErikPhilips sure, either way works, I think... can't see a big advantage one way or the other.

Comment: @Kugel I could see that... one thing we can all agree on is that null should not be returned. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is variable scope. dbaseman almost had it right... do this:

```
public ActionResult GetReport(string pNum)
{
....

    ActionResult actionResult = new View(); // This would typically be assigned a
                                        // default ActionResult
    switch (methodId)
    {
        case 1:
        case 5:                
        {
            actionResult = GetP1Report("33996",false) as ActionResult;
            break;
         }
     }

     return actionResult; 
 }
```

Comment: You need to declare `actionResult = null` or you will get a `use of unassigned local variable "actionResult"` compiler error.